# Why am I getting a segmentation fault after printf("ID | Name | Qty. | Price\n\n");?

Tags: c, shopping-cart

```
    void displayAllProduct()
{
    FILE *filep;
    struct Product a;
    int id, found=0;

    system("clear");
    filep=fopen("fileproduct.txt","w+");
    printf("===========================================================================================\n");
    printf("\t\t Product Details\n\n");
    printf("===========================================================================================\n");

    printf("ID | Name | Qty. | Price\n\n");

    while(1) //infinite loop
    {
        printf("182");
        fread(&a,sizeof(a),1,filep);
        printf("184");
        if(feof(filep))
        {
            break; //done
        }
        printf("%d\t %s\t %d\t %d\n",a.id, a.name,  a.qty, a.price);
    }
    printf("===========================================================================================\n");
    fclose(filep);
}
```

I am currently trying to make a shopping cart for my c programming class but I continuously get a segmentation fault when trying to view my inventory. Above is my function to display the products.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At least, please show us declaration of `struct Product`.

Comment: Check if `fopen()` was successful and try to read the file only if it is successfully opened.

Comment: @MikeCAT, you don't need to check the return value of `fopen` in this case, as the OP is opening it in `w+` mode. If file does not exist, it will get created.

Comment: You're opening `fileproduct.txt` with mode `w+`, i.e. for writing, not reading.  Change the mode to `r` if you want to read from it.

Comment: Use `fflush(stdout);` after calling `printf()` to force what is passed to `printf()` be printed.

Comment: @TomKarzes What if the file doesn't exist and the user doesn't have the permission to write to the directory?

Comment: @MikeCAT If it doesn't exist, then he can't read it, obviously.  He's trying to read an existing file.

Comment: fread expects an input stream, yet you are using a stream opened with w+. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

Comment: @kvr This question is about C, not C++.

Comment: Don't know what platform is being used, but my ubuntu 14.04 man page for fopen says "w+ Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does  not  exist,  otherwise  it  is truncated.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file."  Therefore "reading" is OK... but whatever was in the file before the fopen is removed (i.e. truncated).  Take "@Tom Karzes" suggestion, and change fopen's mode to "r".

Comment: @TonyB I agree, hence my suggestion with the documentation of fread

Answer (score 0):

You are not verifying the return value of `fopen`, which may
fail due to permissions, etc. Segmentation fault happens
on **NULL** pointer de-reference, and that may be happening
here. Few things you can do:

1. After `fopen`, do:

   ```
   if (!filep) {
       perror("fopen");
       exit(1);
   }
   ```
2. Put newline after your debug prints, with a `fflush` also.

Comment: BTW, your existing file will be overwritten to zero bytes, since you open the file in "w+" mode, so read will return feof() immediately. You need to fix that too, but this does not cause the segmentation fault.